# What's the reason behind the sudden influx of the English word "word" in Chinese slang?

Tags: meaning, etymology, internet-slang

I just got a push notification:

> word天! .....

and it's not the first I've gotten with the English word "**word**" in it.

Here's a quick baidu:

> 焦点资讯

> 新闻| Word天,这款润滑油要逆天! 
> 1小时前 搜狐汽车

> 厉害word哥!武警总队高标准完成马拉松警卫任务 
> 5小时前 凤凰网

> 厉害了word亲 国美超市生活百货9.9元最后一天限时秒杀 
> 10小时前 新浪新闻

What's the meaning/reason for sudden influx in usage of English word "word" in Chinese?

Comment: A newly popular slang is "厉害了我的哥", which means "Bravo, my bro". There are quite a number of variants.

Comment: It is because “word” sounds like “我的”。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

word 天 is chinese slang for 我的天.

With an increasing English skill level of Chinese speakers, Chinglish or rather the Chinese counter part of Chinglish is becoming more and more common.

1. Names are often translated using English sounds with Chinese chracters. Ex: Stanford University = 斯坦福大學
2. Some store names are starting to use English sounds with Chinese characters
   Bread Ice / 不賴的冰 http://sunyat.pixnet.net/blog/post/63815917-%E9%AB%98%E9%9B%84-bread-ice%E4%B8%8D%E8%B3%B4%E7%9A%84%E5%86%B0-%7C-%E5%8F%A4%E6%97%A9%E5%86%B0%2B%E5%B8%95%E5%B0%BC%E5%B0%BC%EF%BC%8C%E7%9C%9F%E7%9A%84
3. But these words are not limited to only English. Some even use the local dialect (Taiwanese) and convert it to Standard Chinese. 阿兜仔 is taiwanese slang for forienger (specifically white foriengers) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5WUtW0Dvik

I think overall it's just people becoming more and more creative with how they use slang.

Answer (score 1):

“Word” is prounounced almost the same as Chinese “我的” （My）， 天 means “heaven，God”，so

```
Word天 ＝ 我的天 ＝ My God
```

Now you get the idea.

Hope this helps.